# Mean subtraction of input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

Is it when I define a binaryproto mean file in a prototxt file, it will subtract the mean in the background (Caffe internally does that) from the input automatically? Or should I write an implementation (that implements the mean subtraction from input) to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining `mean_file` in `"Data"` layer parameters caffe will subtract the mean values from the inputs. It is already implemented in caffe for training and validation.

Note that when you deploy your network you will need to manually subtract the mean.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot Shai for the information. I will mark it correct in a few minutes for your answer.